# Laravel Query Builder pass multiple parameters as comma seperated list not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I am using the spatie/laravel-query-builder to make a scope filter.
In the documentation I read this:

> You can even pass multiple parameters to the scope by passing a comma
>   separated list to the filter:
>
> ```
> GET /events?filter[starts_between]=2018-01-01,2018-12-31
> ```

So I made a scope filter in my model that looks like this:

```
public function scopeStartsBetween(Builder $query, $dates): Builder
{
    dd($dates);

    return $query->whereBetween('created_at', array($dates[0], $dates[1]));
}
```

My request looks like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?filter[starts_between]=2018-10-15,2018-10-17
```

The result of the `dd($dates)` is this:

```
"2018-10-15"
```

So the comma seperated list for multiple parameters doesn't work, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try `filter[starts_between][]=2018-01-01&filter[starts_between][]=2018-12-31`

Comment: can you show  your route for this request?

Comment: @urfusion I found the issue check out my answer :) upvote and accept if possible please

Answer (score 7):

Class `FiltersScope` return `...$values`

explaining what this mean by link [Meaning of Three dot (...) in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124015/meaning-of-three-dot-in-php)

In Model scope function we must use same construction, for example

```
public function scopeStartsBetween(Builder $query, ...$dates): Builder
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the multiple parameters should be handled as separate parameters for the scope function:

```
public function scopeStartsBetween(Builder $query, $from, $to): Builder
{
    return $query->whereBetween('created_at', array(Carbon::parse($from), Carbon::parse($to)));
}
```

This does the trick.