# Laravel - Passing array to @can Blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I registered a Gate that should accept an array of integers. Its function is to return **true** if the **user's role id** is in that passed array. The code looks like this:

```
Gate::define('access', function ($user, $access_type) {
            Log::info('-----------------------------------');
            Log::info($access_type);
            Log::info(gettype($access_type));
            Log::info('-----------------------------------');

            return in_array($user->roleid,$access_type);
});
```

And in my template I placed that restriction like this:

```
@can('access',[2,4])
     ... html code here ...
@endcan
```

Now I get this error on the page:

[image]

I looked on the logs to check the value and type of the variable **$access_type**, and it looks like it only gets the value 2.. The 4 value is missing.

[image]

It looks like I have to add another variable on the anonymous function to get the value 4. Like this one:

```
Gate::define('access', function ($user, $access_type1, $access_type2){
  ... some code ...
})
```

When I added the new variable $access_type2 and looked at the logs, I was able to see the value 4.
[image]

> Now my problem is this:
>
> - I can't manually add the variables on the anonymous function because    the values being passed differs in numbers. It can receive
>     1 value, 2    values, 3 values, and etc. How can receive the values in
>     array    format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
Gate::define('access', function ($user, ...$access_types){
  ... some code ...
});
```

The `...$str` is called a [splat operator in PHP](http://lornajane.net/posts/2014/php-5-6-and-the-splat-operator).

This feature allows you to capture a variable number of arguments to a function, combined with "normal" arguments passed in if you like.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41124083/6514992)