# Get the max value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm pretty new to PHP and i'm stuck in the following scenario. I have an array with some values and I want to get the max value in the array set.

For ex:

```
$array = array(
     0 => array(
        '1' => '123',
        '2' => '120',
        '3' => '30',
        '4' => '150'
     ),
     1 => array( 
        '1' => '123',
        '2' => '122',
        '3' => '30',
        '4' => '158'
     ),
     2 => array(
        '1' => '123',
        '2' => '129',
        '3' => '300',
        '4' => '150'
     )
);
```

The value i'm expecting is 300.
I have tried the following code and i don't know how to get the maximum value from all the sub arrays.

```
$max = 0;
foreach( $array as $k => $v ){
  //this is where i need help

 }
```

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can flatten your array first using `array_merge(...$array)`, then just use the `max()` function:

```
$new_array = array_merge(...$array);
echo max($new_array);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/XldKC)

Comment: Just to clarrify.Why would you use ...$array in array merge

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124015/meaning-of-three-dot-in-php)

Comment: `array_merge()` accept a list of arrays as the argument, array_merge(...$array) means `$array` contain the list of array that needed to be merged together.

Answer (score 0):

I took @Hirumina's solution and just set `$max = $y` if `$y` was > `$max`

```
$max = 0;
foreach( $array as $k => $v ) {
    foreach($v as $x => $y) {
        if($y > $max){
            $max = $y;
        }
    }
}
echo $max;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_array = array_map(function($value){
    return max($value);
}, $array);
echo max($new_array);
```

Here array_map function will get max value from individual **$array** and store in **$new_array**.
Then **max($new_array)** will give you max value.

Comment: Code only responses are not recommended on Stack Overflow. Please consider adding comments that explain how this code will help address OP's question. Please read about what to do when someone [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question.

Comment: Can you please add some comment or explanation how it's.