# PHP implode in bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to create an advanced search in php. The inputs are not required, users can decide if they want to search for a manufacturer or just set the minimum price, etc. I'm trying to save the "s" and "i" for the bind_param in an array, and the variables in another array, then implode them in the bind_param part.
This is where I got the problem. The $params implode works fine, but when I'm trying to implode the $vars array, I get the error message that says "Only variables should be passed by reference".
It's because if I push a variable to my array, it stores it's value and not the variable itself. I've tried to push them as strings, like '$example', but in this case, when I implode it, got the same message because it's a string.
So, how should I store them in the array to be able to use them in the bind_param?

In this example I show only 2 inputs, but ofc I have a lot more.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && isset($_GET['search_button'])) {
    $params[] = "i";
    $vars[] = '$status';
    $sql_search = 'SELECT m.*, u.premium, u.avatar FROM motorcycles m INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = m.userid WHERE status = ?';

    if (isset($_GET['manufacturer_search']) && $_GET['manufacturer_search'] !== "") {
        $manufacturer_search = $_GET['manufacturer_search'];
        $sql_search .= " AND manufacturer LIKE ?";
        array_push($params, 's');
        array_push($vars, '$manufacturer_search');
    }

    if (isset($_GET['min_price']) && $_GET['min_price'] !== "") {
        $min_price = $_GET['min_price'];
        $sql_search .= " AND price >= ?";
        array_push($params, 'i');
        array_push($vars, '$min_price');
    }

    $sql_search .= " ORDER BY u.premium DESC LIMIT ?, ?";
    array_push($params, 'ii');
    array_push($vars, '$this_page_first_result', '$results_per_page');


    $stmt_search = $link->prepare($sql_search);
    $stmt_search->bind_param(implode("", $params), implode(",", $vars));
    $stmt_search->execute();
    $result = $stmt_search->get_result();
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you are supposed to provide the variables you want prepared in your statement when calling `bind_param`, `implode` however creates a string. Try the following; `$stmt_search->bind_param(implode("", $params), ...$vars );`

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that we don't know how many parameters will the user use in the search, so I can't just put all my variables there. Sometimes the user will use only 1 input, but sometimes 4. I'm trying to make it dynamic, but don't know how to put the variables there.

Comment: Your edit really solved the problem. Thank you so much. If you write it as an answer, I can accept it. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide the variables you want separately as the last parameter of `bind_params`, what you are doing is creating a string of all your variables and passing that.

Change

```
$stmt_search->bind_param(implode("", $params), implode(",", $vars));
```

To

```
$stmt_search->bind_param(implode("", $params), ...$vars );
```

And PHP will take all entries inside your `$vars` array and pass them as separate parameters of the function.

For more information on this see the [Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) of `bind_param`, PHP's introduction of the `splat operator` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics) and some [extra information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124015/meaning-of-three-dot-in-php) on stack overflow.